# SpamAssassin rules explaination

Tags: spamassassin

I have a little problem with *SpamAssassin*. I don't find the documentation for the rules.

For example for the rule `MIME_HTML_MOSTLY` I have this link : https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/MIME_HTML_MOSTLY
But apparently the documentation is no longer available and I didn't find the new link.

Could you please help me to find the new wiki link ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've extracted all rules definitions and pasted them in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ychaouche/a2faff159c2a1fea16019156972c7f8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what SpamAssassin support answered me :

> The wiki was mostly migrated to the ASF Confluence instance recently and
>   is now at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/. The
>   old rules descriptions (which had not been maintained since v3.3) were
>   not migrated, as they were largely outdated where they were not
>   redundant.
>
> I don't have a definitive reference for the decision to stop maintaining
>   rule descriptions on the wiki, so there may be a more correct
>   explanation out there in the heads of the people who were on the PMC at
>   the time. However, my view is that this was the right decision because
>   of how the default rules are managed. Rules can shift in and out of the
>   update channel based on the automated QA process, and there is a
>   continuous trickle of new rules, rule changes, and rule deletions coming
>   from the development team that get integrated (or not) via RuleQA. There
>   was never a functional process for maintaining the wiki pages for rules
>   properly in conjunction with that continuous change process, and the
>   descriptions were mostly not much more illuminating than the 'describe'
>   lines in the rules files.

Answer (score 1):

Not all rules are documented on the SpamAssassin wiki — there's way too many of them to do that. You can get automated [efficacy data for `MIME_HTML_MOSTLY`](https://ruleqa.spamassassin.org/latest/MIME_HTML_MOSTLY/detail) from the SpamAssassin Rule QA system, but not the definition.

The current definition for that rule (discounting translations) from [rules/20_body_tests.cf](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/spamassassin/trunk/rules/20_body_tests.cf?view=markup) is:

```perl
# … line 139 (quite likely to change)
body MIME_HTML_MOSTLY       eval:check_mime_multipart_ratio('0.00','0.01')
describe MIME_HTML_MOSTLY   Multipart message mostly text/html MIME
# … rules/50_scores.cf line 616 (also quite likely to change)
score MIME_HTML_MOSTLY 0.1
```

This is an eval rule, so you'll have to look at the perl code to see exactly what it's doing.

In [lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/MIMEEval.pm](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/spamassassin/trunk/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/MIMEEval.pm?view=markup), you'll find:

```perl
# … line 214
sub check_mime_multipart_ratio {
  my ($self, $pms, undef, $min, $max) = @_;

  $self->_check_attachments($pms) unless exists $pms->{mime_checked_attachments};
  return 0 unless exists $pms->{mime_multipart_ratio};
  return ($pms->{mime_multipart_ratio} >= $min &&
      $pms->{mime_multipart_ratio} < $max);
}

# … line 491
    if (defined($text) && defined($html) && $html > 0) {
      $pms->{mime_multipart_ratio} = ($text / $html);
    }
```

This means the ratio of the text MIME part's length to the HTML MIME part's length must be equal to or above zero and also under 1%.

(Line numbers are from the current trunk repository, not a release. The code shouldn't change much, but the line numbers likely will, especially within the `.cf` files.)

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer. But I thought they moved their wiki to a different location. If you look in the archives of the apache wiki (http://web.archive.org/web/20170913151929/https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/MIME_HTML_MOSTLY), there's a good explanation for that message. Do you know if this wiki is still available?

Comment: (I didn't mention any SpamAssassin wikis...) I'm a bit out of touch with SA dev. You could ask the [SpamAssassin Users mailing list](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/spamassassin/MailingLists#MailingLists-Users), but I'm pretty sure the old wiki is retired in favor of Confluence.

Comment: I must admit that my problem wasn't clear and I'm sorry for this... I just want to find the new wiki link.

Comment: You wanted a wiki link that doesn't exist and you complain when I provide significantly more information than that wiki link would or than the archived link you already had did‽ Some things get lost in migrations. I'm guessing the folks maintaining the SA wiki decided that piecemeal documentation on rules was unwise since it was never going to even approach a comprehensive list, so it was eschewed from the migration.